# Three players play chess until 2 consecutive wins, given a player has sat out at trial n, what is the probability they will win overall?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I have attempted this question from Feller's Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications (chapter 5, question 14, page 141), but I keep coming up with a slightly different answer. The question is below but the context is that you have players a, b, and c. Two play, one sits out and then winner stays on. The tournament ends when a player gets two consecutive wins. The probability of winning a game is $\frac{1}{2}$ for all:

> In example (2.a) let $x_n$ be the conditional probability that the winner of the $n^{th}$ trial wins the entire game given that the game does not terminate at the $n^{th}$ trial; let $y_n$ and $z_n$ be the corresponding probabilities of victory for the losing and pausing player, respectively, of the $n^{th}$ trial. (a) Show that: $x_n = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}y_{n+1}$; $y_n = \frac{1}{2}z_{n+1}$; $z_n = \frac{1}{2}x_{n+1}$

I can get the first two but I am struggling with the third. I had that it should be $z_n = \frac{1}{2}x_{n+1} + \frac{1}{2}y_{n+1}$ because the person sitting out can either have win-win (game ends), win-lose (win later) or lose (win later). It seems like $\frac{1}{2}x_{n+1}$ term only covers the WW and WL scenarios so we would need the y term.

What have I misunderstood here?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please consider using MathJax for typesetting mathematical expressions in your posts. Additionally, please take a tour and try to explore what is considered a good question on this site. In particular, your question title is NOT and should NOT be the first line of your post.

Comment: @math-physicist Thank you for the advice. I have changed my maths so that it uses MathJax. For the question format I was just wondering what part wasn't good form? Is it the fact that I've quoted the question I'm trying to answer? It's quite a lengthy thing to explain in the title so I thought putting the question might be good but I can change this if that's the issue. Thanks again

Comment: If the player sitting out the n-th trial loses in round n+1 the game is over (and he has no chance of winning anymore). I.e. your case „lose (win later)“ is not possible.

Comment: Ah of course! I completely missed that! Thank you so much!!